# Проблема с удалением файла в php

Tags: php, файлы

Не могу удалить 2 файла, путь которых указан в БД, вот код:

```
            $img = "'" . '../' . $row['news_imgpath'] . "'";
        $file = "'" . '../' . $row['news_pagepath'] . "'";

        if (is_file($img)) {

           chmod($img, 0777);

           if (unlink($img)) {
              echo 'File deleted';
           } else {
              echo 'Cannot remove that file';
           }

        } 
        else {
        }
        if (is_file($file)) {

           chmod($file, 0777);

           if (unlink($file)) {
              echo 'File deleted';
           } else {
              echo 'Cannot remove that file';
           }

        } 
        else {
        }
```

Comment: что значит не могу удалить? Есть warning'и?

Comment: @vp_arth затупил думаю у него в скрипте проблема с путями через var_damp посмотреть где что и все будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы собираете некорректное имя файла:

```
$file = "'" . '../' . $row['news_pagepath'] . "'";
```

Зачем эти апострофы?

```
$file = '../' . $row['news_pagepath'];
```

Всегда лучше собирать абсолютный путь, во избежание разночтений:

```
$file = realpath(__DIR__ . '/../' . $row['news_pagepath']);
```